# Rotate an element between two points using LookAt

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two functions:

- drawing `Line` between points
- drawing `Cube` between points

The `line` is drawn correctly. The `Cube`, on the other hand, becomes perpendicular (GIF)

What am I doing wrong?

```
GameObject lineRenderer = new GameObject();
lineRenderer.name = "TempLine";
lineRenderer.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
lineRenderer.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, startPoint);
lineRenderer.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, endPoint);

var between = endPoint - startPoint;
var distance = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
var mesh = ShapeGenerator.CreateShape(ShapeType.Cube);
mesh.name = "TestMesh";

mesh.transform.position = startPoint + (between / 2.0f);
mesh.transform.LookAt(endPoint);

mesh.transform.localScale = new Vector3(distance, 5f, 0.2f);

//mesh.transform.Translate(new Vector3(2000, 0, 0), Space.World);
```

[image]

Comment: Look at rotates it thus that the local **forward** vectors points to the target position .. if you don't want that just rotate it additionally about 90°

Comment: change to ```mesh.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, 5f, distance); ``` look at use the z coordinate as the forward vector

Answer (score 1):

change

```
mesh.transform.localScale = new Vector3(distance, 5f, 0.2f);
```

to

```
mesh.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, 5f, distance);
```

LookAt use the z coordinate as the forward vector of your object.

Comment: I have checked this solution before. Visually it works but the local coordinate system changes. There should be an X axis along the element and here will be a Z axis. This spoils the whole concept of how elements work

Comment: A solution that works is to add: `mesh.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(mesh.transform.eulerAngles.x, mesh.transform.eulerAngles.y - 90f, mesh.transform.eulerAngles.z);`. But it's like fixing a bug. I am not entirely convinced of it.